# Components of bipartite graphs that are trees

Tags: graph-theory

Hi, I apologize if this question is poorly formed as I'm not a graph theorist.  I've figured out how to encode some information about a problem in surface topology in the language of graph theory.  I just can't figure out how to prove it in graph theory or where to look for more information.

Given some $n$, suppose I have two sets of vertices $V=\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ and $W=\{w_1,...,w_l\}$ with $k,l$ strictly less than $n$ where each vertex is assigned a degree $d_{v_i}$ or $d_{w_j}$, respectively.  Suppose I know there exists a bipartite graph with $n$ edges from $V$ to $W$ respecting the given degrees of each vertex that is a forest.  I would like to be able to say that this implies every bipartite graph with $n$ edges from $V$ to $W$ that respects the given degrees contains a component that is a tree.  Is there any chance this is true or any references that could help me figure it out?  I do also have the additional information that the only cycles I can allow are 2-cycles.  Does this help anything?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but a finite forest has strictly fewer edges than vertices.  And a finite graph with no acyclic connected component has at least as many edges as vertices.  Does this give you what you want?

Comment: Not quite.  Both $k$ and $l$ are less than $n$, but their sum should be, so the total number of vertices is more than $n$, however the number on each side is less.

Comment: @hungrygrad, let me rephrase Clinton Conley's argument in your notation.  The existence of a forest on your sets of vertices with n edges implies that k+l>n.  But there exist no graphs with k+l vertices all of whose connected components contain cycles (i.e. have no components that are trees), as all such graphs must have at least k+l edges, which was strictly greater than n.

Comment: Oh, great, now it makes sense.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @hungrygrad If you are satisfied with the answers given, please accept the community wiki answer below so your question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Clinton Conley, Jul 13 '11 at 22:19 answered:

> A finite forest has strictly fewer edges than vertices. And a finite graph with no acyclic connected component has at least as many edges as vertices.

j.c., Jul 14 '11 at 5:12 clarified:

> The existence of a forest on your sets of vertices with $n$ edges implies that $k+l>n$. But there exist no graphs with $k+l$ vertices all of whose connected components contain cycles (i.e. have no components that are trees), as all such graphs must have at least $k+l$ edges, which was strictly greater than $n$.